# Stop citrix' icaclient unit to spam systemd's journal

Tags: systemd-journald, citrix

I installed [the citrix icaclient](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icaclient/) to be able to connect to my company's citrix server, but unfortunately, that software spams my journal log. This time, it either spawns a message:

```
Okt 15 09:57:55 jupiter citrix-wfica[772593]: doEncryptData inbuffersize: 3
Okt 15 09:57:55 jupiter citrix-wfica[772593]: SSLPutDataFn inbuffersize: 32
```

either every 3 seconds or for almost every pixel I move the mouse over the window (hundreds of occurrences per second). How can I either

- Prevent the app to log that message / anything into journal
- Make journal ignore this unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue using the Citrix Workspace (configmgr) and disabled all logging.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in the file `/etc/init.d/ctxlogd`.
It uses `/sbin/runuser` which does not exist on my OpenSUSE Leap.
Use `/usr/sbin/runuser` instead!

Line 87:   `if /usr/sbin/runuser $CitrixUser -s "$DAEMON"`

When I set `ctxlogd` enabled/started everything runs smoothly.